# How to import a GIF into a template created in Photoshop CS4?

Tags: photoshop-cs4

I want my GIF image to be imported in my Photoshop work. I am creating a web template For which I need the Image.

Comment: Please post these kind of questions (non programming related) on superuser.com

Comment: @jdehaan: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [nonprogramming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222) or "belongs-on".

Answer (score 1):

Import of gif in PS CS4 was lost and added later in PS CS5

However in CS4 you can try as below and see if it works:

Go to File->Import->Video Frames to Layers

In the File Name box type “*” ( or you can type the name manually) The window will now show every type of file.Select your gif image